# How to write a Required validation , so that one of the search fields should have value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AdvanceSearchIndex","Home",
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "get",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    LoadingElementId = "progress",
    UpdateTargetId = "SearchTable"
}))
{





    <p><span class="f">IP Address <input  placeholder="Search by IP " name="ip" type="text"  /> </span></p>
   <p><span class="f">MAC Address <input  placeholder="Search by Mac " name="mac" type="text"  /> </span></p>




<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="search" /> 

<img src="~/Content/Ajax-loader-bar.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progress" />

    }
```

but i need to write a javaScript code so that either the IP Address OR MAc Address , is not null or empty , when clicking on the Search button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also answered you here: [How to implement a Required validation to check if the user enter atleast one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669815/how-to-implement-a-required-validation-to-check-if-the-user-enter-atleast-one-va/19675203#19675203)

```
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AdvanceSearchIndex","Home",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "get",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            LoadingElementId = "progress",
            UpdateTargetId = "SearchTable",
            OnBegin = "validateForm"//note this line calling js function
        }))
        {  

            <p><span class="f">IP Address <input  placeholder="Search by IP " name="ip" type="text"  /> </span></p>
           <p><span class="f">MAC Address <input  placeholder="Search by Mac " name="mac" type="text"  /> </span></p>

        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="search" /> 

        <img src="~/Content/Ajax-loader-bar.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progress" />
    }

        <script>
        function validateForm(){
           //return true/false
           return $("[name=ip]").val() !="" || $("[name=nac]").val()
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Did you add this: OnBegin = "validateForm", I added  this on the ajaxoptions